# Identify which compute instance a static external IP address is associated with

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to identify which compute instances a static external IP address is associated with? I see the following chain of connection:

```
address -> forwarding rule -> target proxy -> url map -> backend service -> instance group
```

Now I can list the instances contained in the eventual instance group. But this is a long chain to follow. Is there any idiomatic way to achieve this quickly, or will I need to script this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `gcloud` can list the external IPs of an instance:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list
NAME  ZONE          MACHINE_TYPE   ...  EXTERNAL_IP  STATUS
test  asia-east1-a  n1-standard-1  ...  1.1.1.1      RUNNING
...
```

If you run again with the `--verbosity info` flag, you'll see that the EXTERNAL_IP row in the column comes from (see [`gcloud topic formats`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) and [`gcloud topic projections`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections)):

```
networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[0].natIP.notnull().list():label=EXTERNAL_IP
```

You can get a list of all of the NAT IPs for an instance via (notice the dropped `0` for `accessConfigs`; this aggregates all NAT IPs:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list \
      --format 'value(networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[].natIP)'
[u'1.1.1.1']
[u'1.1.1.2']
...
```

With a specific IP in mind, you can turn that into a [filter expression](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters):

```
$ gcloud compute instances list \
      --filter 'networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[].natIP:1.1.1.1'
NAME  ZONE          MACHINE_TYPE   ...  EXTERNAL_IP  STATUS
test  asia-east1-a  n1-standard-1  ...  1.1.1.1      RUNNING
...
```

This works for me when the instance is part of an instance group.

Comment: I feel almost silly having asked the question, didn't think about it from the other side. Thanks for your help.